# How do I replace an external javascript array on the Vue js array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I'm still a beginner in Vue.js and I have a problem. I have this code:

```
data: function(){
        return {
        search: '',
        zenes: [
          { id: '1', name: 'Jhon Snow', profile_pic: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png'},
          { id: '2', name: 'Deanerys Targarian', profile_pic: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png'},
          { id: '3', name: 'Jaime Lanister', profile_pic: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png'},
          { id: '4', name: 'Tyron Lanister', profile_pic: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png'}
        ]};
},
```

This code is really good but i would like to use in my application so I would like to change zenes:[....], to an external javascript code:

```
<script>var zenecim = <%- zenecim %></script>//these are big arrays thousands  of items
<script>var zenesrc = <%- zenesrc %></script>
```

I would like to see like this or something like that:

```
zenes:[id:(this is the indexof the array),name:zenecim,src:zenesrc]
```

Thank you very much for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to receive external data your choices are pretty much limited to either using a [prop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) on a component or you can use an AJAX request with something like [Axios](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html) for example.

Of course you can set window globals and access them but that is something you really don't want to be doing.

The context of your problem is missing here therefore I can not judge what would be the best pick here.

Comment: so far I've got the items to be scanned in the array to just transform them into the form described above